# Linking Boost Libraries in Linux Cent OS 7.0

Tags: c++, linux, boost

My IDE is Clion, but I think it doesn't matter since it uses **CMakeLists.txt**.

Here is my **main.cpp** in which I include boost **filesystem.hpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(AsioFirst)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories("/usr/local/src/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/")

link_directories("/usr/local/src/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(AsioFirst ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But when I run that (using arguments -`lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem`), I get the following error which is probably a linking error:

```
boost::system::generic_category()
```

Directories are double checked, and they are correct.

Comment: Could you please post the full output from your compiler (the complete error message it gives)? It compiles fine on my machine.

Comment: I have posted an answer which I had found just before your commenting. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I recommend you have a look at using `FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)` for a more portable result.

Answer (score 2):

Do not hardcode your dependencies/library paths. Better use [find_package command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/find_package.html) to find Boosts include directories and libraries:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(AsioFirst)

#Add a hint about your boost copy
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/src/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(AsioFirst ${SOURCE_FILES})

#More portable than setting CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
set_property(TARGET AsioFirst PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
target_include_directories(AsioFirst PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(AsioFirst PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Don't you also need to set `link_directories`?

Comment: @mindriot Can't see why. Boost_LIBRARIES is all you need.

Comment: I always thought that depends on what compiler is used and/or what the linker command line ends up looking like. If the `.so` files are specified directly with their complete path, you would be right, but if the command line ends up containing `-lboost_system`, you'd _definitely_ need a `-L` here due to the library being in a non-standard location.

Comment: I just checked this. It does not seem to be required as the FindBoost script simply uses full paths if needed.

Comment: Ah, OK, That would be a special case of FindBoost then.

Comment: According to the link_directories documentation this is to expect: [Library locations returned by find_package() and find_library() are absolute paths.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/link_directories.html)

Answer (score -1):

I post this for future visitors:
The solution was that I should have added the exact link to the libraries used:

```
link_libraries("/usr/local/src/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/libboost_system.so")
link_libraries("/usr/local/src/boost_1_60_0/boost_1_60_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so")
```

It seems the arguments `lboost_system  -lboost_filesystem` did not resolve the linking.